# Does the Back Button fail to call stop()?

Tags: android, codenameone

My app currently has only one Form, which listens to the accelerometer sensor. In my `start()` method, I turn the listener on, and in the `stop()` method, I turn it off. I have verified that the listener turns off when I hit the Android's home button, but when I hit the back button, the application exits and the Android returns to the home screen, but the listener keeps going, which means the `stop()` method never got called. Is it my responsibility to handle the back button with code to call the `stop()` method? Or is this a bug in CodenameOne's framework? It seems to me that when the back button returns the user to the home screen, it should call `stop()` for me.

Comment: This seems like a bug in codenameone, we will fix this. thanks

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the bug Chen?

Comment: yes, this is already fixed in the open source repository.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Comment: FYI we deploy fixes every Friday so it should be on device builds by next Friday at the latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. I've verified it, and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about all the details of your issue, however you can resolve it by calling the setBackCommand on that one form.

```
yourForm.setBackCommand(  
                        new Command("closing the sensor listener"){
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
                                // your code to close the listener
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CodenameOne framework, but I know the `Android SDK`.

`Activity.onBackPressed()` should be invoked when you use the back button.  Just because your Activity is no longer visible does not mean it has been reaped, and this might explain why `Activity.stop()` is not invoked (immediately).

Depending upon your use case, `Activity.onPause()` might also work better.

HTH.  Good luck w/your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CodenameOne framework, but When app is visible and you press back button it calls all four methods in following order

```
1)onBackPressed()
2)onPause()
3)onStop()
4)onDestroy()
```

and when you press home button it calls only

```
1)onPause()
2)onStop()
```

methods
so, when you press back button onStop must be called.
You please put source code so that people can understand your problem clearly.